# Запуск django проекта на сервере

Tags: python, сервер

Запускаю на сервере django проект через python manage.py runserver

В консоле:

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 02, 2023 - 13:20:41
Django version 4.2, using settings 'sitemed.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Но перехожу на страницу в инете wadawdasd.ru (прим.) и ничего не выдает. Страница просто не грузиться. Что сделать?

В Allowed host все написал, миграции сделал, DEBUD=False. Помогите

Хостинговым провайдером просто написано, что нет index.html. Хостинг не видит моего сайта. Не знаю что делать (reg.ru)

Comment: а если запустить `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` ?

Comment: все равно не видит

Comment: покажите структуру проекта своего тогда